# How can I change table names in KIE / Drools persistence?

Tags: jpa, drools, jbpm

My question is pretty straightforward. My `persistence.xml` looks like this:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="org.jbpm.domain" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/jbpm</jta-data-source>

        <!-- SessionInfo -->
        <class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            ...
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And this creates `SessionInfo` and `SESSIONINFO_ID_SEQ` tables in my database. However, these names are not in our organisational standards, and I am trying to change the table names at least (and the column names if I could). How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using an `orm.xml` file under `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF`, which looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<entity-mappings
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">

    <entity class="org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo">
        <table name="session_info"/>
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <column name="id"/>
                <generated-value generator="session_info_id_seq" strategy="SEQUENCE"/>
                <sequence-generator name="session_info_id_seq" sequence-name="session_info_id_seq"/>
            </id>
            <basic name="lastModificationDate">
                <column name="last_modification_date"/>
            </basic>
            <basic name="rulesByteArray">
                <column name="rules_byte_array"/>
            </basic>
            <basic name="startDate">
                <column name="start_date"/>
            </basic>
            <version name="version">
                <column name="optlock"/>
            </version>
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

For further reference on XML overriding: [Here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/xml-overriding.html)'s the official guide.